# How do I get rid of a pattern forming on my model?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a couch but this pattern keep forming on the one side of it, how do I get rid of it? Help. It appeared after I extruded a little bit.

[image]

Comment: What a nice flower. But if you didn't mean to have it then the mesh has bad topology and likely Subsurf modifer. So some cleaning up work will be needed.

Comment: I'll try doing that

Comment: @Mr Zak yes, I guess it's one of those patterns you would not be able to intentionally reproduce it...

Comment: @Alex to get more help it could be better to show actual topology (edit mode) with subsurf modifier disabled...

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to the question: the wire frame representation of the mesh and one without the subsurf modifier enabled. Consider also uploading your file.

Comment: It kind of looks like the pattern that forms when You use sub surf on the default cylinder. To me, it looks like the faces where this is occurring is not a quad, meaning it doesn't have four points. If you make them into quads it could help. Also, you could try restarting your computer. If that doesnt work you could import the objects into a new file or start over.